# regex for dns logs

Tags: regex, logging, dns

I have a DNS logs that come like this :

```
17/04/2017 08:59:38 09DC PACKET  000000A939E64600 UDP Rcv 10.254.30.96    c650   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (8)master11(10)teamviewer(3)com(0)
17/04/2017 08:59:38 09DC PACKET  000000A9404FABE0 UDP Rcv 10.254.30.87    9bae   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (7)master2(10)teamviewer(3)com(0)
17/04/2017 08:59:42 09E0 PACKET  000000A9404D15B0 UDP Rcv 10.254.35.43    fdcc   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (6)mobile(4)pipe(4)aria(9)microsoft(3)com(0)
17/04/2017 09:49:45 09E8 PACKET  000000A94194FE80 UDP Rcv 8.8.8.8         646d R Q [8381   DR NXDOMAIN] A      (3)mta(3)dkf(2)com(0)
```

In the end of each line you will the see the domain name represented like this:

```
(7)master2(10)teamviewer(3)com(0)
```

I wanted to get only the following parts :

```
master teamviewer com
```

and replace the the space by a "." to have a result like this :

```
master2.teamviewer.com
```

To do that I used this regex :

```
(?<=\)).*?(?=\()
```

But unfortunately i got this error :

```
Lookbehind is not supported in javascript
```

Do any one have a suggestion or a solution of this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are doing. Try replacing with `s.replace(/\([^\s()]+\)(?=\S*$)/g, '.')`.

Comment: Does capturing work in a specific way there? Try `\)([^()]+)\(` (in QRADAR, not at the regex building Web site)

Comment: Please check [this site](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/350963/qradar-regex-in-dsm-editopr.html). Is it the same software you are dealing with?

Comment: Well, if the previous regex only captured all the numbers, maybe you need a regex that will match all text other than what you need? Try `^.* |\([^\s()]+\)(?=\S*$)`

Comment: I will post for you to accept then

Comment: Could you please share in the comment? Was it `\s+\(\d+\)(.*?)\(\d+\)(.*?)\(\d+\)(.*?)\(\d+\)` and `Capture group` set to `1`? It won't work for `(6)mobile(4)pipe(4)aria(9)microsoft(3)com(0)`

Comment: Ok, I see, adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the solution from [this article](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/350963/qradar-regex-in-dsm-editopr.html):

```
A\s+\(\d+\)(.*?)\(\d+\)(.*?)\(\d+\)(.*?)\(\d+\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SytKoI/4)

Here,

- `A` - a literal `A`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\(\d+\)`  - 1+ digits enclosed with `(` and `)`
- `(.*?)` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible (as `*?` is a lazy quantifier)
- `\(\d+\)(.*?)\(\d+\)(.*?)\(\d+\)` - an alternated sequence of the above two subpatterns.

Set the *Capture Group* option as needed. In the example above,

```
Format String : $1.$2.$3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
\(\d+\)(?:[\w]+\(\d+\))+
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SxHX23/3)

```js
const regex = /\(\d+\)(?:[\w]+\(\d+\))+/g;
const str = `17/04/2017 08:59:38 09DC PACKET  000000A939E64600 UDP Rcv 10.254.30.96    c650   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (8)master11(10)teamviewer(3)com(0)
17/04/2017 08:59:38 09DC PACKET  000000A9404FABE0 UDP Rcv 10.254.30.87    9bae   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (7)master2(10)teamviewer(3)com(0)
17/04/2017 08:59:42 09E0 PACKET  000000A9404D15B0 UDP Rcv 10.254.35.43    fdcc   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (6)mobile(4)pipe(4)aria(9)microsoft(3)com(0)
17/04/2017 09:49:45 09E8 PACKET  000000A94194FE80 UDP Rcv 8.8.8.8         646d R Q [8381   DR NXDOMAIN] A      (3)mta(3)dkf(2)com(0)
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
console.log(m[0].split(/\(\d+\)/).filter(val => val).join("."));
}
```

Comment: OP is not using JavaScript, but a JS regex *flavor* in QRADAR.